# update rows where length > 50

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, truncate

I have a table lets call it 'People' and it has a column called 'Name' lets say it used to have column specification of Varchar(500) and now it will be changed to Varchar(100)

What TSQL can I write to do this update and basically trim each row where a row contains a name > 100 chars

Ive got this so far to identify the rows, I know how to update rows, so do I need a cursor or is there some other efficient way? (Only about 100 rows)

```
SELECT Id, LEFT (Name, 100) FROM People
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to condition on LEN(Name) which is the length of the Name field.

```
UPDATE People
SET Name = LEFT(Name, 100)
WHERE LEN(Name) > 100
```

Comment: BTW the title says "length > 50" but your question said length > 100 so I left it to match the question not the title.

Answer (score 0):

No need to apply CURSOR for this. And one should always AVOID the use of CURSORS.

Check this solution, another way in which this can be done.

```
Update People 
Set Name = Case When Len(Name) > 5 THen Left(Name, 5) else Name End
```